# Listen to Prosody Offline messages directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, push-notification, xmpp, listen

I have developed a chat application using Prosody and I need to send a push notification when someone receives a message and isn't online.

This chat application works together with my WebApp written in Ruby on Rails.

I searched a lot and didn't found anything that sends push notifications from Prosody(I found for eJabberd but I had another problems with eJabberd). So I decided to look for a gem to RoR that monitors a directory, with that I can monitor the Prosody's offline message directory and get a callback when a message couldn't be delivered to a user and then send a push notification to him.

I found the gem Listen from guard(https://github.com/guard/listen) that do exactly what I need, but I don't know where I should start the listener and when I should stop it since I need it to run aways my WebApp is online.

Comment: Does the push notification need to come from your rails app? Could it be sent from a separate process?

Comment: @mtm It can be sent from another process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make too over-complicated things, just because you think Prosody is a "black box". In fact you need:

- prosody module, which "hooks" offline message and send it to your webapp - see example here: https://github.com/JorgenPhi/ProsodyPush
- push notification module for your favorite web framework - I think you can find tons of ruby gems for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but ProsodyPush is in beta yet. In the description is said to don't use in production.

Comment: @jonathanrz, the source code of this module is less then description, open it and see how simple to write prosody modules, also open prosody documentation and other modules, and you will understand how your "I will not use prosody modules because one of these modules in "beta stage" is silly.

Comment: I already implemented my solution and I don't have time to change it know, I need to finish this project. But I agree with your points and because that I accepted your answer to further documentation.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I found that the best way is to write just a simple ruby script and daemonize him with daemons(https://github.com/ghazel/daemons).

To treat the push notification in my rails app I will use the forward_to option from listen to call an action of my rails app.

Thanks to @mtm for the rails cast explaining how to daemonize a script: http://railscasts.com/episodes/129-custom-daemon

Comment: you got to what I was going to suggest. There is a [rails plugin](https://github.com/dougal/daemon_generator/tree/master) that makes managing daemons easier which is detailed in an old [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/129-custom-daemon).

Comment: Thank you for the rails cast, I will update the answer.